# Guacamole SFTP not working for larger files

Tags: ssh, sftp, rdp, libssh2, guacamole

I am using guacamole to connect to remote devices over RDP for Windows machines and SSH for Linux. Now I would like to enable SFTP support for the connections so I enabled the option 'Enable SFTP' in the guacamole connection settings.

The problem is SFTP is working for smaller files (<3KB), creates 0KB files for slightly larger files (3KB-150KB) and raises internal error for larger files (>150KB). I checked for what file size SFTP is failing by trial, transferring files of different sizes to the remote machine.

[image: Screenshot of the SFTP error in guacamole]

In the screenshot, it can be seen that 'attendance.py' a smaller file of size 548 bytes is successfully transferred to the tmp folder in the Linux machine, but the other two files files are created as empty files. The pdf file I tried to move is close to 180KB, which raises a Internal Error. I checked if there is some dependency with this error and filetype but this problem occurs for all file formats. I have the same problem when transferring file to a windows machine configured with RDP protocol in the same guacamole server.

Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a reverse Proxy?
I had the same problem by using nginx. It seems it is by default not allowing files greater than 1MB.
I could change that at nginx to any size and now it works.

For nginx look for: client_max_body_size

If you are not using nginx, i would take a look at the webserver config. Remember, you using some sort of a webserver and a filelimit is there usualy very much needed.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30304048)